# How to match color scheme of spatial lines, circle markers in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, geospatial, spatial

I'm wondering how I can color GPS locations and tracks that are created from a sequential order of points in leaflet. I've figured out how to color the circle markers by a grouping variable (TagID), but I'm not sure how to do the same for SpatialLines based off of my GPS locations.

## Load the libraries ------------------------------------------------------

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(lubridate)
library(here)

here()
source('points_to_lines.R')
```

The points to line source code can be found here https://rpubs.com/walkerke/points_to_line

## Load the tracking data ----------------------------------------------------------

```
locs <- 
structure(list(TagID = c("174025", "174025", "174025", "174025", 
"174025", "174025", "174025", "174025", "174025", "174025", "174025", 
"174026", "174026", "174026", "174026", "174026", "174026", "174026", 
"174026", "174026"), Date = structure(c(17555, 17557, 17559, 
17561, 17563, 17565, 17573, 17575, 17577, 17581, 17583, 17557, 
17559, 17561, 17563, 17569, 17571, 17573, 17575, 17577), class = "Date"), 
Time = structure(c(64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 
64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 
64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), Latitude = c(27.7423229, 27.7405567, 
27.7406845, 27.7423992, 27.7397385, 27.7404804, 27.7398396, 
27.739687, 27.7419643, 27.7400951, 27.7399673, 27.6441727, 
27.6432247, 27.6460419, 27.6436863, 27.6445313, 27.6447868, 
27.6444798, 27.6433029, 27.6445065), Longitude = c(-97.1295395, 
-97.1274109, -97.1275101, -97.1295624, -97.1317902, -97.1309433, 
-97.1313248, -97.1259537, -97.1296158, -97.1268997, -97.1318893, 
-97.8031235, -97.803688, -97.8094711, -97.8035049, -97.8067551, 
-97.8031998, -97.8071671, -97.8036575, -97.8047867), Fix = c("3D", 
"3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", 
"3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D"), Sequence = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)), .Names = c("TagID", "Date", "Time", 
"Latitude", "Longitude", "Fix", "Sequence"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

## Map in leaflet ----------------------------------------------------------

```
# Create the colors for each tag code
pal = colorFactor('Spectral', locs$TagID)

# Turn the points into a SpatialLinesDataFrame to plot sequential points
# i.e., a track
tracks <- points_to_line(data = locs, 
                     long = "Longitude", 
                     lat = "Latitude", 
                     id_field = "TagID", 
                     sort_field = "Sequence")
tracks
```

Is there a way to color spatial lines below in a similar fashion (so using a color palette like I created for the circle markers)?

```
# Plot everything (points and tracks) in a leaflet map
leaflet(locs) %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", 
               group = "CartoDB") %>%
addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", 
               group = "Satellite") %>%
addCircleMarkers(~Longitude, 
               ~Latitude, 
               weight = 1, 
               group="Tagged birds", 
               color = ~pal(TagID),
               radius = 5, 
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               popup=paste("<b>", "TagID:", "</b>", locs$TagID, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Lat:", "</b>", locs$Latitude, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Long:", "</b>", locs$Longitude, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Date:", "</b>", locs$Date, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Time:", "</b>", locs$Time, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Fix type:", "</b>", locs$Fix, "<br>",
                           "<b>", "Fix #:", "</b>", locs$Sequence)) %>%
addPolylines(data = tracks, 
           opacity = 0.4,
           color = c("red", "orange"),
           group = "Tagged birds") %>%
addLayersControl(position = 'bottomleft',
               baseGroups = c("CartoDB", "Satellite"), 
               overlayGroups = "Tagged birds",
               options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
addLegend(position = 'bottomleft',
        pal = pal, 
        values = ~TagID,
        labels = ~TagID,
        title = "TagID")
```

The leaflet map can be viewed here http://rpubs.com/jmwiniarski/trackingmap

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand this question. On the map you've linked to your lines are the same colour as the circles. And to use the same colours you use the same `pal`

Comment: @SymbolixAU using color=pal for 'addPolylines' does not work, so I have to enter colors manually...